# Why am I unable to delegate handlers to this scroll event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).on('scroll','.archives_container',function(){
    console.log("Hello World");
})
```

However, scrolling through the `.archives_container` div doesn't seem to set off the handler. Why is this?

JsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/VRP8t/

Comment: The scroll event does not bubble.

Comment: why do you use a delegated event..? http://jsfiddle.net/honk1/VRP8t/1/

Comment: @j08691 What does that mean?

Comment: you should set the scroll function to the element, not the entire document.

Comment: It means that your code is attempting to catch an event as it propagates up the DOM, which the scroll event doesn't do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a workaround: {not handling all scroll case :(}

```
$(document).one('mouseenter','.hello', function(){
    $(this).on('scroll',function(){
        console.log('scrolling');
    });
});
```